# How to make my algorithm significantly faster by reduce for loops?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, api

I am currently working on a project that collects data from the masslottery.com api. I am analyzing this data in all sorts of ways. One way I would like to analyze this data is by checking what 5 spot keno number has come in the most over, lets say the last year. My program that I have written can theoretically do this. However, it is a bit too slow. Right now checking a 3 spot number takes about a minute and 20 seconds. And as you know the number of possibilities I have to count go up and up as you increase numbers. Since keno is 1-80,

```
80 choose 3 = 82,160 possibilities
80 choose 4 = 1,581,580 possibilities
80 choose 5 =  24,040,016 possibilities
```

So as you can see if my program takes a minute on only 80 thousand, it would take like 5 hours to finish for a 5 spot number. With that said I am looking for help on how to speed up my program. I believe my issue is my double for loop but I've tried everything to fix this. I will include my code below.

```
import requests
from itertools import combinations
import operator
import collections
r = requests.get('https://www.masslottery.com/rest/keno/getDrawsByDateRange?startDate=2021-01-01=&endDate=2021-07-11').json()
draw  = (r['draws'])
dict = {}

spot = int(input('How many spots are you trying to check? '))


arr = [
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12,
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79,
80]
test = combinations(arr,spot)

count= 0
print('Starting Check')
for i in test:
    dict[str(sorted(i))] = 0


for num in draw:
    numbers = num['winningNumbers']
    combin = combinations(numbers,spot)
    for j in combin:
        temp = str(sorted(j))
        dict[temp] = dict[temp] + 1




sorted_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
dict2 = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_dict)
filename = str(spot) + 'spotTest.txt'
with open(filename,'w') as File:
    for i in dict2:
        File.write(str(i) + '---->'+ str(dict2[i]) +'\n')
        
print('Done')
```

NOTE: Also I am aware that keno is a game of luck and has no strategy involved. I am only doing this for my entertainment purposes and to practice coding. Thanks to anyone that has ideas on how to speed this up!

Comment: You can look at defaultdict, so that you don't need to initialize the dictionary for combinations that never occured at all. 

additionally (it will not increase the speed in any meaningful way), note that combinations from itertools are already sorted. also the key can be a tuple just fine, so 
`dict[i] = dict[i] + 1` is fine using defaultdict

Comment: Since I am searching over such a large period of time, every combination does come in at least 600 times. I will change my sorting code. I did not realize it came sorted. Thanks!

Comment: It may not be as slow as you expect.  C(20,5) is only 13.6 times larger than C(20,3) so you should only need to wait for about a quarter of an hour.

Comment: Ill give it a try and time it for about 20 minutes or so.

Comment: Actually, I just realized why you may be off. Its 80 C 5 and 80 C 3. Not 20. So I think it would end up taking about 5 hours. Which is so slow

Comment: The clearing `for i in test` is 80 C 5, but this should not be the slow path.  The slow path should be `for j in combin` which is 20 C 5 because numbers is length 20.  I suggest printing out something on each iteration through `for num in draw` so you can see the progress being made and estimate the total time remaining.

Comment: I see now why you used 20. I did run it for about 17 minutes yesterday with no outcome. I will give it a try and see how long the for num in draw takes. However I’d obviously still like to make this much faster because my goal is to go back further than 2021.

Comment: I ran the code without the for j in combin And it finished in about 2 minutes, but the the for num in draw took seconds to run. So the for j in combin is for sure the slow part.

Comment: Have you considered using recursion if it can lower the steps in the search? I know that in general it may be less efficient but I have seen cases where if you lower the steps enough it becomes more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I'll focus on the technical side of the exact solution to your problem. Note, that if this was a real life problem, you'd probably end up using some kind of approximate frequency analysis instead of optimizing the exact solution.

---

Now, here are several things that can improve the performance of your program.

#### 1. Use the appropriate data structure, avoid garbage

Python dictionaries are hash tables underneath. That means that they allocate  huge continuous array (table) to hold references to your data. If you're actively inserting millions of elements into the dict, at some point it has to grow, meaning new larger array is allocated and old array is copied to the new one. As you can imagine, this is not fast, especially for large arrays.

Generating sorted string keys for combinations is a reasonable approach on a small scale, but not if you're doing it millions of times in a loop.

Instead of using `dict` with string keys, you can use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The Trie is a n-ary tree (in your case each node will have at most 80 children), with counters in the leafs. Also, for this problem, as you're storing combinations, each node of the trie will be strictly smaller than its parent.

[image: trie]

Here you have combinations `{2, 3, 20}` with count=1  and `{4,79, 80}` with count=2 stored in the trie.

If you look at the subsequent combinations, generated by itertools, you'll notice that most of the time they are different only in the last element. The algorithm to generate combinations plays very well with Trie traversal. In fact, you can do both using the same recursive function. When you generate new combination, you don't need to traverse the whole Trie to the leaf, you've already did most of the work for the previous combination!

The signature of this function will look something like this:

```py
def rec(arr, i=-1, rem=spot, node=root):
```

Where:

- `arr` is your winning number to generate combinations from (sorted asc)
- `i` is the last index of the element in the current combination (-1 if there are none yet)
- `rem` is the number of elements left to generate in current combination
- `node` is the parent Trie node (node that corresponds to the last element of the current combination, or `root` if there are none)

When `rem` reaches `0`, you bump the counter in the `node`.

So, the overall algorithm would be:

1. Go through all winning numbers
2. Sort winning number in ascending order
3. Run `rec` for the current winning number

   - `rec` will generate all combinations out of the winning number, bumping counters in the Trie at the same time
   - Note: don't initialize the Trie with all possible combinations beforehand, it wastes time, and you can always find out which numbers are missing, when traversing the Trie, if you even need that
4. Recursively traverse the Trie to find maximal number or dump everything in the file

#### 2. Parallellize!

There is a popular paradigm for parallel data processing, called [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). There are lots of frameworks that utilize this approach, but it's not necessary to use them.

This problem is a perfect use case for map-reduce. You have your big data (winning numbers), that you can partition into several chunks.

Then, you have your "map" stage — generating dict (or trie) from the combinations from winning numbers.

Finally, when you have counters from each partition, you can merge them into a single dictionary/trie. This is "reduce" stage.

Now, that may sound simple, but there are several important things to consider:

1. In python, due to [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) using threads within the same process may not yield the desired performance gain. If you're sticking with python, you'll probably need to spawn separate process for each input partition and dump the results into a file and then merge the files
2. Merging sorted file is relatively easy and can be done in linear time using `merge` method, similar to the one from [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Merging dicts is pretty straightforward. Merging trie is also easy, you basically need to traverse both tries at the same time.

#### 3. Get closer to the bare metal

Python is an awesome language for quick prototyping or gluing native code together. However, if you're trying to squeeze every bit of performance out of your machine, you may consider rewriting your code in a more performant language. Same code in C++ or Rust can be orders of magnitude faster than in Python. Even Java can get you some performance improvement.